# Can't take text from a textarea asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following textarea declared inside an aspx page

```
Continut:<TextArea maxlength="4000" ID="Continut" name="Continut" runat="server" style="background-color: white; border : 1px solid #cccccc; width : 700px; height : 250px; resize : none;"></TextArea>
```

and I want to take the text from this textarea in C#. The code I use in C# looks like this

```
this.Request.Form["Continut"].Length < 1? "":this.Request.Form["Continut"]
```

Is there anything I do wrong or I just didn't fully understand how this works?

P.S. : I tried with another code and i get an eror that says : "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea' does not contain a definition for 'Text'".
And the code is :

```
this.Continut.Text.Length < 1? "Document":this.Continut.Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad1) Make sure that your control "Continut" is inside form. 
Ad2) You should use Value property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltextarea.value(v=vs.110).aspx